# How to get circleCI to work with protractor baseurl

Tags: angularjs, continuous-integration, protractor, circleci

I'm trying to set up CI on CircleCI and running into an error when trying to run Protractor with a test server via baseUrl.

```
protractor protractor/config.js --baseUrl='http://tenant1.my-app.com/' 
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:365
  onError(new Error(message));
          ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:365:15)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1249:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at acquireSession (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
at Function.createSession (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
at Builder.build (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:42:27)
at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:203:37)
at /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:293:21
at _fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
at /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49

[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Any thoughts on how to get protractor to connect with the test server?

Comment: Are you running this locally or is this the output from circleCI?  This error looks like your webdriver isn't running -- `webdriver-manager start`

Comment: This is the output from circleCI.  Everything runs fine on local machine

Comment: @Vijay - Can you share your circle.yml file ?

Comment: make sure to use the 'debug via SSH' feature of circleci to help debugging your issue

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the environment variable wrong—it isn't passed as a flag to protractor, it should be set as an environment variable before running the command, e.g.

Command:

```
BASE_URL='http://localhost:1337/api/' protractor protractor.conf.js
```

Output:

```
[11:09:21] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:09:21] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub


  Test describe
>>> env var for process.env.BASE_URL:  http://localhost:1337/api/
    ✓ test case


  1 passing (279ms)

[11:09:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:09:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

The tests that need to use the base URL would access them off `process.env`:

```
it('test case', () => {
  console.log('>>> env var for process.env.BASE_URL: ', process.env.BASE_URL);
});
```

So to open a URL at the base URL, you would use protractor's browser like so:

```
browser.get(process.env.BASE_URL + 'path/to/endpoint');
```